# Lower bound for monochromatic triangles on 2 coloring of $K_n$

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I am trying to show that there is at least $\frac{n(n-1)(n-5)}{24}$ monochromatic triangles in any 2 coloring of the edges of $K_n$.  I am trying to show this using [Mantel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n's_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem) but I can't seem to find a direction to go.

I have tried to determine how many non triangles there are on some fixed vertex but I don't see where to take the proof from there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: upper bound the number of triples $(u, v, w)$ of vertices such that the edges $(u, v)$ and $(v, w)$ have different colors (this will happen when $v$ is incident to roughly the same number of red and blue edges). Each non-triangle is associated to 2 such triples, and each triple belongs to exactly one non-triangle.

Comment: I actually meant to say that it is an edge coloring, but I am thinking that this hint could still be applicable.

Comment: This hint was under the assumption that is an edge coloring. I see why it could be confusing though; by "v connected to roughly the same number of red and blue vertices" I actually meant "incident to roughly the same number of red and blue edges". I've fixed it now.

Comment: I am pretty close to getting the answer.  I have found that the upper bound for number of non-monochromatic triangles is $\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right \rfloor \left \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right \rceil$ and there are ${n \choose 3}$ total triangles.  It seems that it is a matter of subtracting the number of non triangles from the total number of triangles but I can't seem to get the desired answer.  I am supposed to come up with the lower bound for monochromatic triangles as $\frac{n(n-1)(n-5)}{24}$.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't think to account for every possible fixed vertex and divide by 2.  It looks like doing that gives the desired result.